# Building non-deterministic automata

Tags: automata, nondeterminism

I'm trying to make non deterministic automata for specific language .
I cant understand my mistake!
Rules:
1){a,b,c}
2) if I have the sequence "bb" and later in the word I have the sequence "cc" so this is not possible that I have the sequence "cba" between them.
Thank you !

[image]

Comment: so the language consists of all strings such that if they have $bb$ and $cc$ in that order, then there shouldn't be the string $cba$ in between them?

Comment: @Jamāl yes!!!!!

Comment: Why is it downvoted? I would do the following: 1) Build NFA for the complement language (it's pretty simple). 2) Build a corresponding DFA (there is a standard algorithm). 3) Convert to DFA for the original language (given a DFA, it's trivial to find a DFA for the complement language).

Comment: The only problem I see is that $q4$ may need and transition to itself {a,b,c}. Without this, all strings in the language must end in `cc`. You should post the language this NFA is supposed to accept.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this question to the best of my ability. Feel free to ask for any clarification or raise any doubts in the comments.

[image]

Apart from issues like nullifying the effect of some useful transitions, the problem in your solution is that you've started out at a rejecting state, but unless the string has encountered $bb$ and then $cba$ and subsequently $cc$, it should be accepted.

I've laid out the transitions in a step wise manner, jumping about the states to "reset" the logic that proceeds to rejecting state.

**Update:**
You can think about the automata as comprising of $3$ parts. q0,q1 check for first occurrence of $bb$. q2,q3,q4 detect the string $cba$. Finally, q5,q6,q7 test for the string $cc$.